# fopen fails (permission denied) even though all parent folders are 775

Tags: php, centos, fopen, chmod

I'm trying to create a file from PHP using the following code:

```
$config_file = fopen( '/home/the-user/domains/the-domain/public_html/the-folder/the-file.php', 'w');
```

The folder that this file is going to be in is created by DirectAdmin. So PHP will usually not have access to this folder. Because of this I added the `apache` user to the group of the user which is used by DirectAdmin.

I'm using the following to change the permissions of the newly created folder:

`exec('sudo chmod 775 /home/the-user/domains/the-domain/public_html/the-folder/');`

Even after doing all of this I still get the `failed to open stream: Permission denied` error.

I've looked through many different posts and I think I tried almost everything without success.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear PHP doesn't have write access to the file. Now since you have not mentioned which OS and webserver you are running i have to make a couple of assumptions, since this is obviously Unix the commands are gonna be the same but the webserver that you use will determine which **runuser** requires the access(this following example will be for apache on ubuntu)

so make sure the file is writable by the `www-data` user/group.

```
exec('sudo chown www-data:www-data /home/the-user/domains/the-domain/public_html/the-folder/');
```

or via the command line

```
chown www-data:www-data /home/the-user/domains/the-domain/public_html/the-folder/
```

this will change the user/group of that specific file.

To check which user your webserver is running under you can use the following command to output a list of all processes and their runuser

```
ps auxf | more
```

One other thing to keep in mind is security off course `chmod 755`, i would not recommend using this for php files as a general rule of thumb i follow this.

> Files are generally 644 and folders are 755. That's for normal operation.
>
> Certain files to be marked read-only are often set to 444 or in some cases 400.